# Angular form is not valid until I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I am not sure how to diagnose this issue. I have an Angular 4.x app that uses firebase (via angularfire2).

The user logs in, and is redirected to the home page where they can register Visitors (this is a kiosk-style application).

The issue I am having is that when a user logs in, the registration form (just a single email input at this step) is "invalid" and won't update the form. The classes on the input and form seems to be stuck on `ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid`. If I refresh the page (or change tabs), the input and form can update to `ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid`.

Here is a gif of the issue (hope it helps?):
[image: my issue]

I thought that it could be Material Design, so I removed the material design wrapper from my input. As you can see that didn't have any affect. There are no errors in the log... I am not sure how to diagnose or solve this one.

Here is my code:
`registration.component.html`

```
<reg-wizard [wizardTitle]="'Registration'" #regWizard>
  <ng-container wizard-steps>
    <!--STEP 1: LOOK UP EMAIL-->
    <reg-wizard-step (onNext)="lookupEmail($event)" [isValid]="emailForm.form.valid">
      <form #emailForm="ngForm">
        <md-input-container class="w100">
          <input mdInput placeholder="Email" email [(ngModel)]="formData.email" name="email" type="email" required>
        </md-input-container>
      </form>
    </reg-wizard-step>
<!--(more steps...)-->
  </ng-container>
</reg-wizard>
```

`registration.component.html`

```
import {Component, ContentChildren, OnDestroy, OnInit, QueryList, AfterContentInit} from '@angular/core';
import {RegistrationService} from '../../services/registration.service';
import {FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {FirebaseService} from '../../services/firebase.service';
import {MdInputContainer, MdSnackBar} from '@angular/material';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {RouteGlobals} from '../../route-globals';
import {HowHearService} from '../../services/how-hear.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'reg-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.scss']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  formData = {
    'email': '',
    'firstName': '',
    'lastName': '',
    'tel': '',
    'howHear': '',
    'howHearDetails': '',
    'canContact': true // default value
  };

  isCompleted = false;
  searching = true;
  requiresMoreInfo$ = Observable.of(false);
  step2Text;
  incrementVisitCount = true;
  visitorStatusSubscription;

  howHearOptions$;


  constructor(private registrationService: RegistrationService, private router: Router, private routeGlobals: RouteGlobals,
              private firebaseService: FirebaseService, private howHearService: HowHearService,
              private snackBar: MdSnackBar) {
    this.howHearOptions$ = howHearService.getHowHears();
    this.clearFormData();
    console.log('constructor');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  // reloadPage() {
  //   window.location.reload();
  // }

  startOver() {
    this.clearFormData();
    this.router.navigate([this.routeGlobals.registrationPath]);
  }

  onComplete(event) {
    // if status 1, then don't increment count
    // navigate dont reload
    console.log(this.firebaseService.userObj$.getValue().currentEvent);
    this.isCompleted = true;
    this.registrationService.upsertVisitor(this.formData, this.firebaseService.userObj$.getValue().currentEvent, this.incrementVisitCount);
    this.snackBar.open('Thank you for registering!', '', {duration: 1500});
  }

  lookupEmail(event) {
    this.searching = true;
    this.incrementVisitCount = true; // reset if needed

    this.visitorStatusSubscription = this.registrationService.getVisitorStatus(this.formData['email']).first().subscribe(res => {
      console.log('new function', res);
      switch (res.status) {
        case 1: // registered for this event.
          this.step2Text = 'You have already been registered for this event. Please review your information to verify it is accurate.';
          this.formData = res.visitor;
          this.searching = false;
          this.requiresMoreInfo$ = this.howHearService.requiresMoreInfo(res.visitor.howHear);
          this.incrementVisitCount = false;
          break;
        case 0: // registered for a previous event.
          this.step2Text = 'Welcome back! Please review your information to verify it is accurate.';
          this.formData = res.visitor;
          this.searching = false;
          this.requiresMoreInfo$ = this.howHearService.requiresMoreInfo(res.visitor.howHear);
          break;
        case -1: // new visitor
        default:
          // TODO: this could come from the event.
          this.step2Text = 'Thank you for visiting! Please enter your information to register.';
          this.clearFormData(this.formData['email']);
          this.searching = false;
      }
    });
  }

  howHearSelectChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.value);
    console.log(event.value.$key);
    // this.formData.howHear = event.value.$key;
    if (event.value) {
      this.requiresMoreInfo$ = this.howHearService.requiresMoreInfo(event.value);
    }
  }

  clearFormData(retainEmail?: string) {
    // console.log('email retain? ', retainEmail);
    let tempEmail = '';
    if (retainEmail) {
      tempEmail = retainEmail;
    }
    this.formData.email = tempEmail;
    this.formData.canContact = true;
    this.formData.tel = '';
    this.formData.firstName = '';
    this.formData.lastName = '';
    this.formData.howHear = '';
    this.formData.howHearDetails = '';

    // reset defaults
    this.isCompleted = false;
    this.searching = true;
    this.incrementVisitCount = true;
    this.requiresMoreInfo$ = Observable.of(false);

    console.log('subscription', this.visitorStatusSubscription);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log('destroying');
    if (this.visitorStatusSubscription && !this.visitorStatusSubscription.closed) {
      this.visitorStatusSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice to see a gif, but also could be helpful to see your code! ;)

Comment: Which code would be helpful? my login code? the html? or the ts for this page?

Comment: I think the template+component of this page would be alright.